# How to compute the symmetric of a point (high dimension space) with respect to a hyperplane formed by a set of points?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen3

I'm using C++ and I want to calculate the symmetric of a point with respect to a hyperplane. I'm in a **dimension given at execution time**.

I have the points in the hyperplane. So I calculated the normal vector by solving a set of linear equations. Then to get the hyperplane (with the normal and a point), the projection of the first point and finally the symmetric.

I tried using the `eigen3` library but it seems it needs the dimension to be given at compile time.

Any idea to solve the problem with this library (or any other one) or a short-cut method are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigen can work with both compile-time and run-time sizes. To use run-time size, specify `Dynamic` or use predefined aliases:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> x(n);
```

or just

```
Eigen::VectorXd x(n);
```

where `n` is your runtime-specified number of dimensions.

See documentation [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html#TutorialMatrixDynamic)

---

Once you have computed the normal vector and the origin (simply one of your points), you can do this:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

using namespace Eigen;

VectorXd mirror(const VectorXd &normal, const VectorXd &origin, const VectorXd &x)
{
    return x - 2.0 * normal * ((x-origin).dot(normal)) / normal.dot(normal);
}
```

[image]

Comment: OK. I didn't know about the keyword dynamic. That gets me rid of one problem. Is the way I want calculate the symmetric the good one though ?